# Is the wheel important in a sling trainer?

Tags: exercise-equipment

I'm considering getting myself a sling trainer, after I was able to try one at a gym.

I found one major difference between cheap ones, and expensive ones (as the one on the gym), which is the wheel, which makes the string between the handles move really easy I guess.

Here is one without wheel: ([Product](http://www.amazon.de/SportPlus-Schlingentrainer-Professional-Karabinerbefestigung-Transportbeutel/dp/B00KE4JXAK/ref=sr_1_1?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1462705218&sr=1-1&keywords=schlingentrainer))

And here one with wheel: ([Product](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00SHAIBVA?psc=1))

I'm thinking, the wheel is important and in order to get the full effect of a sling trainer I should get one with wheel, but before I put the order I'd like to get some input from some more experienced people.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the query. The pully wheel is vital to get right. I have constructed a couple of my own, only to discover that I could purchase the whole unit online much cheaper.
Go for a large wheel with swivel, check the dimentions well, and study the photos to see if it is robust and well constructed. The sling straps need to be abrasion resistant also. Good luck with your search.
David of Cornwall